# Big O with n*logn(n) and n*log(n^2)

Tags: big-o

So I recently encountered a question which asked to order different functions in growth order where g1=O(g2), etc and to partition the list into equivalence classes iff f(n)=(theta O)(gn). In the answers for the question, it listed n*log(n) to be growing slower than n*log(n^2) (which makes sense) but then under the list, it said that n*log(n) and n*log(n^2) have the same growth rate. How does that work?

Comment: Consider that `log(a^b) = b log(a)`. What's "weird O" though?

Comment: @harold: Probably an Omega (Ω) or Theta (Θ) character.

Comment: My bad, I should've specified. It's theta. I just didn't know how to put the symbol in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That comes from the distribution of power over log -- log(n<sup>2</sup>) = 2log(n), so
 O(n log(n<sup>2</sup>)) = O(2n log(n)) = O(n log(n))